# Extra Header Files Created After Build in IAR Workbench

Tags: c, build, header-files, iar

I learn embedded programming with STM32F401RE in IAR Workbench.

I am confused about header file creation after build. Here below my question:

In the below file structure of IAR Workbench before build only a c file and there is no header file in the user folder

[image]

However after build process there are many header file in the user folder file.
My question is what is the purpose of  the header file in it.

In addition to that question all headers files must be involved before build process?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You need to read IAR's documentation about the build process. Perhaps they like to copy all included header files into your project's source tree. (It feels like bad style, however. But they may have good reasons.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I research your suggestion and share the reason why they choice this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are all header files that you have included in your main.c file, either directly or indirectly. Most at least are IAR library headers that come with the compiler. They are not created, but instead detected to be in use when you build your project.

For example, if you `#include <stdio.h>` in your source file, then stdio.h will be on that list. And all files that stdio.h includes will also be on that list. And then all includes from those included files are also on that list.

IAR library header files have typically have a lot of nested includes in them. Most likely you have at least one IAR library `#include` in your main.c file, or you have preincluded in a library header with your compiler command.